# How to set the intelephense workspace for CoC phpls?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I'm using [coc-phpls](https://github.com/marlonfan/coc-phpls/) to edit a plugin project inside a bigger project.

i.e. the dir structure is like

```
/var/www/example/
/var/www/example/libraries/
/var/www/example/plugins/myplugin  ← my working dir.
```

Because I started in `myplugin/` then intelephense only looks for symbols in files within that dir; but I need it to hunt for the top of the project, i.e. `/var/www/example`.

I'm using [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/) which lets me include a .vim file from an ancestor dir. But the intelephense settings are in a json file in `~/.config/nvim/coc-settings.json`

How can I set this dynamically?

I'm using neovim 0.5.0.

Comment: Have you tried using [`:h :cd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Acd)/[`:h :lcd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Alcd)? I don't know if coc respects that but that could be a way to do it. Otherwise you might have more success asking directly in [coc's issue tracker](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.vim/coc-settings.json` file in the root of your project, i.e. `/var/www/example/.vim/coc-settings.json`

In here you can add settings to override the global ones. Enter this:

```json
{
  "coc.preferences.rootPatterns": [
    ".thisIsDocRoot"
  ]
}
```

This tells CoC to look for a `.thisIsDocRoot` file to determine a "workspace" dir.

Next `touch /var/www/example/.thisIsDocRoot` to create a file in the doc root.

Now when you edit a file in `/var/www/example/plugins/myplugin` CoC will:

- scan up the tree looking for `.vim/coc-settings.json` which it will find at the root of your project. It merges that config.
- that causes it to then look for `.thisIsDocRoot`, which again it finds in the root of the project.
- Intelephense now uses this to find symbols.

Note: you might also want to tell it to look in files other than .php ones, e.g. Drupal uses .module and .inc files too. To cover this, my
`/var/www/example/.vim/coc-settings.json` file is:

```json
{
  "coc.preferences.rootPatterns": [
    ".thisIsDocRoot"
  ],
  "intelephense.files.associations": [
    "*.php",
    "*.module",
    "*.inc"
  ],
  "cSpell.userWords": [
    "DRUPAL"
  ]
}
```

[Red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring): Intelephense defines a config item called `intelephense.environment.documentRoot`. I tried putting a value in this in various coc-settings files to no avail.